# Condense Laravel blade if(old()) statement down

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following working code in my `create` view

```
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" @if(old('contact_preferences') && in_array('post', old('contact_preferences'))) checked @endif value="post" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Post</span>
  </label>
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" @if(old('contact_preferences') && in_array('email', old('contact_preferences'))) checked @endif value="email" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">E-Mail</span>
  </label>            
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" @if(old('contact_preferences') && in_array('phone', old('contact_preferences'))) checked @endif value="phone" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Phone</span>
  </label>
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" @if(old('contact_preferences') && in_array('none', old('contact_preferences'))) checked @endif value="none" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">None</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm using checkboxes to mark the choices a user has made. But my if statement to show these checkboxes as `checked` on failure of other validation rules is jarring my brain a bit; it works, but seems unnecessarily long.

Is there some blade magic I can do that I'm not aware of to shorten the statement at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to shorten your condition by use of a [null coalesce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) instead of a check for the entry's existence:

```
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" @if(in_array('post', old('contact_preferences') ?? [])) checked @endif value="post" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Post</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And another option — I actually wasn't aware you could do inline `@if`/`@endif` on a single line like that. What I always do is a simple [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and [echo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data) like this:

```
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <label class="inline-flex items-center">
    <input name="contact_preferences[]" {{ in_array('post', old('contact_preferences') ?? []) ? "checked" : "" }} value="post" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Post</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot, part of my issue however is that if the validation fails elsewhere `contact_preferences` will be `null` and therefor not an array to check inside in_array

Comment: That's why the null coalesce op

Comment: Hah, oh yeah, lemme try this 2 secs

Comment: `@if(in_array('post', old('contact_preferences') ?? [])) checked @endif` worked perfectly, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create function so it will be more 'dry':

```
 <div class="flex justify-between">
        <?php
            function isChecked($name){
                return old('contact_preferences') && in_array($name, old('contact_preferences')) ? 'checked': '';
            }
        ?>
        <label class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input name="contact_preferences[]" {{isChecked('post')}} value="post" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Post</span>
        </label>
        <label class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input name="contact_preferences[]" {{isChecked('email')}} value="email" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">E-Mail</span>
        </label>
        <label class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input name="contact_preferences[]" {{isChecked('phone')}} value="phone" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">Phone</span>
        </label>
        <label class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input name="contact_preferences[]" {{isChecked('none')}} value="none" type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">None</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't really do logic like that in the views though, so this isn't a great solution sadly

Comment: I don't say that this is best possible answer